# jQuery—use a cookie to remember menu position

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery Cycle to paginate a long menu into 5 item chunks or panels—5 items = 1 panel. I've got the code working to slice up the long list, and jQuery Cycle now paginates the list just fine.

But! I need to use a cookie to 'remember' which panel I was on when I click a list item. IE: if I click an item in Panel2, the page will load and my menu will be returned to Panel1 again.

jQuery cycle takes `startingSlide` as an option. How can I use a cookie to set the current panel I'm on? Then, how can I pass this option along to jQuery Cycle as the `startingSlide`?

An example fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/eayZq/2/

In the end, my jQuery Cycle code would look something like this:

```
$('.list').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollVert',
    speed: 'fast',
    timeout: 0,
    prev: '.back',
    next: '.more',
    startingSlide = 'panel-x-that-i-just-clicked-on'
});
```

Anyone know how I can use a cookie to "pass along" the panel number to the next page?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, why don't you just prevent the link from reloading the page?  Using a cookie would be the last option I consider.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just prevent the click from reloading your page?

Here is you example with links added around each `li`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ALsHA/1/

When you click the links, the page doesn't reload, because I `return false;` from the click handler.  This is the same as doing `e.preventDefault()` in the handler as well:

```
$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // This
    alert('You clicked: '+$(this).text());
    return false;  // Or this
});
```

`return false;` does a bit more, but it will also prevent the click from reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. The list is actually a menu, and each item is different page—requiring a new pageload.